# Using the acts-as-taggable-on gem, How to get the most used tags within a period of time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I found the method `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.most_used` but this will return tags created since the beginning of time.

With this command  `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.where('created_at >= ?', 1.day.ago).joins(:tag)`  I can get the latest tags created within a day but I don't know how to use both to get the most used tags within a day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from github @tags = Post.tag_counts_on(:tags)